# Copy files for local Machine to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

A local project directory with its files and sub directory which is used for web app development needs to move to the AWS cloud. And once there, changes in the local machine version often will need to sync with aws version to update it.

The local Mac machine has aws-shell installed.  The app gets built from Dockerfile on EC2 thus the project directory will eventually need to be on the EC2.
Options:
 1. compress locally to 100Mb and scp to EC2, unzip on EC2 and use docker?
 2. compress locally and copy to S3, copy from S3 to EC2?

What commands is used to to pull this off? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. compress locally to 100Mb and scp to EC2, unzip on EC2 and use docker?
>
> What commands is used to to pull this off?

`scp`

> 2. compress locally and copy to S3, copy from S3 to EC2?
>
> What commands is used to to pull this off?

`aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync`

See the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html)